# starting a process unix

Tags: linux, process

When issuing the following command:

```
 ps -ef | grep queue
```

I get a list of 5 processes running.

```
root   10001    1   0   2012  pts/5   02:22:04 /usr/local/perl/bin/perl  /usr/local/cpi/sss/enroll_req - L
root   10003    1   0   2012  pts/5  00:12:44  /usr/local/perl/bin/perl  /usr/local/cpi/sss/job_req -L
```

My question is this.  If I issue a

```
kill 10001
```

How would I restart the enroll_req process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how the process was started in the first place. In the easiest case, it might be enough to just use the command line you see in the `ps` output:

```
/usr/local/perl/bin/perl /usr/local/cpi/sss/enroll_req - L
```

but if this process was spawned, e.g. from some master process doing some initialization, you could run into trouble.

Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: because I've got a perl script which had some changes, I was told the only way to commit those changes once pushed to production was to kill and start the process.   Thanks Sven...not sure why I got voted down 2 votes.

Comment: fyi, thanks Sven.  What you mentioned worked.  I had to append a ampersand to the command in order to get the process to run in the background.  thanks